# Syncronize Microsoft calendars using Microsoft Graph and Daemon application authenticated without user

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api

I want to create a .NET Core daemon application for syncronize all my users' appointment from my application to Outlook and viceversa using Microsoft Graph.

Actually I've already created a daemon application *without user* following this guide: [Get access without a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service) and I've already tested some endpoints like

- *get all users under app's tenant*
- *select id, userPrincipalName of all users under app's tenant*

and these tests work well. Now I would like to implement some tests about calendar, like:

- *given a user (id | userPrincipalName) under app's tenant, check if [name] calendar exists*
- *given a user (id | userPrincipalName) under app's tenant, insert a new calendar*
- *given a user (id | userPrincipalName) under app's tenant, select all his appointments*

and here I have a problem reading this [documentation about list calendar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-calendars?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp) because the example about HTTP request says that I can create a request with the following urls

```
- http request: "GET /me/calendars"
- http request: "GET /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/calendars
```

instead C# example contains only one example about

`- c# graph lib: "graphClient.Me.Calendars.Request() ... "`

Is it possible to execute an HTTP request "/users/{id | userPrincipalName}" using Microsoft.Graph C# library? I am looking through Microsoft Graph library but actually I don't discover any way to implements the previous test.

obviously I can't use *graphClient.Me.Calendars.Request() ... "* because my graphClient is *authenticated without user*

Do I have to use Outlook REST api?

Comment: Try graphClient.Users["xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"].Calendars...

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Randy Slavey I solved my issue.

To create a HTTP Request using {id | userPrincipalName} using Microsoft Graph C# lib you have to write the following code:

`graphClient.Users["xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"].Calendars`